# Cheerio how to get text nodes sibling with other tag

Tags: node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

i have solved this before long ago, but i forgot now.
How i can access that date when my main selector is

`$('.date')`

```
let cheerio = require('cheerio')
let html = `
<html>
    <body>
        <span class="date">
            <span class="category">Article</span>
            Sat, 22 Jan 2021 11:12
        </span>
    </body>
</html>`

let $ = cheerio.load(html)

// Empty
console.log($('.date').next().text())
// Empty
console.log($($('.date').children()[0]).next().next().text())
// Empty
console.log($($('.date').children()[0]).next().text())
// Empty
$('.date').each(el => { console.log($(el).text())})
```

Comment: This works ? `$('.date').contents().last().text()`

Comment: Wow i dont remember i use contents before, Yes! it's work and add .trim() since so much space

Thanks <3 , 1 hour i figure out this

Comment: i didn't see this https://cheerio.js.org/Cheerio.html#contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to comment by @Dario:

The [contents()](https://cheerio.js.org/classes/cheerio.html#contents) function:

> Gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

So you can do this:

```
let cheerio = require('cheerio')
let html = `
<html>
    <body>
        <span class="date">
            <span class="category">Article</span>
            Sat, 22 Jan 2021 11:12
        </span>
    </body>
</html>`

let $ = cheerio.load(html)

let val = $('.date').contents().last().text()

console.log(val.trim())
// prints Sat, 22 Jan 2021 11:12
```